# managing pubnub image subscriptions

Tags: android, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I am implementing a chat application with image sending feature using pubnub, I am able to publish the images.
But while subscribing i am receiving the image link instead of the actual image . I get the message as a JSON object as 
''' 
{"nameValuePairs":{"imageurl":"example.com"}}

''' . 
How do i use it to put it into an Imageview. Here is my code 
(**The publish handler**) 
'''
var image = JSONObject() as JSONObject
image.put("imageurl","example.com")

'''
The message recieved in the subscribe handler is a json object and not the image . Why isn't pubnub catching my image from the external server.

Comment: I do not believe PubNub has the logic to know what to do with your data when it is received. It is on you to grab the image URL, pull the image and attach to your image element. Are you using the PubNub Chat framework or a raw SDK? More details so we can assist further. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use a library called [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). This will manage the downloading and scaling of the image for you. Follow the setup instructions and then simply after receiving the image url use the example code like this:

```
Glide
    .with(activity or fragment, etc.)
    .load(urlFromResponse)
    .centerCrop() // If you want to crop it
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner) // also optional
    .into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 2):

So PubNub won't download and move the image for you, the PubSub messaging bus will move the URL from your publish to the subscribers of the channel.

Because of this I recommend implementing a 'type' of message that represents your image. 
eg:

```
{
        "content": “Hi Team, anyone fancy lunch today?”,
        "type": “Text”,
}
```

An image example:

```
{
      "type":"image",
      "thumbnailURL":"https://cdn.image.server/thumbnail",
      "fullURL":"https://cdn.image.server/full"
}
```

As you know that the incoming message is a 'type' of image you can then place the URL in a factory and load that way:

```
URL url = new URL(pubnubMessage.fullURL);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Hope this helps!